# Fullcalendar v1.5 inside iframe, error in IE!

Tags: fullcalendar

I've to run fullcalendar inside a iframe, and that works well in all browsers besides IE8.

In IE8 the only thing i get is the button with "today", "<", ">" and "day", "month", "week". If the first thing i click on is "month" or "week" a popup tells me:

slotScroller is null or not an object. Line 3209 in fullcalendar.js

If the first thing i click on is "today", "<" or ">" everything is well, but the calendar is initially broken... showing just the buttonrow.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please follow these instructions to submit a bug report?
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/support/

thanks